# Letters don't appear in virtual consoles in debian

Tags: debian, virtual-consoles

Firstly, I switched to some virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2-6</kbd> even right after installing Debian 11 with KDE and, secondly, I tried to type something in that console. No letters appear, but it works with numerals. As you know, a login prompt appears first.

So I can't login in the system via those consoles.

Initially, logged in through the GUI.

Comment: Almost probably a problem with the framebuffer and or kernel modesetting. What video drivers are you using ?

Comment: Since the system was installed, it seems to have been using a default set of Intel drivers.